# Different onTap function in every list items

Tags: list, flutter, navigation

I want to open seperate screen for my each list items

[image: want this]

code

```
     ...index["data"]
                        .map(
                          (index) => Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.h),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    index["onTap"];
                                  },
                                  child: Text(
                                    index["type"],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: AppColors.primaryColor,
                                        fontSize: 13.sp,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 0.3.h,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  index["details"],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 9.3.sp,
                                    color: AppColors.blackColor
                                        .withOpacity(0.8),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList(),
```

List for navigation function and other items
list is in format of List

and use ...list.map => .toList

my list

**List list = [
{
"category": 'Your posts',
"data": [
{
"type": 'Pending posts',
"details": 'fdh fghfg nlfro refglrhgre tghrig ffr gk',
"onTap": () {
print('++++++++++++');     //// function for navigation to screen 1
},
},
];
**

Comment: You should really use proper models for this, not a dynamic map. Every time you use `dynamic` explicitely or implicitely by omitting the actual type, you cheat yourself out of compiler support you could have had. Your compiler would have told you where the problem was, if it had known what you were doing. You hid your intent from your compiler and you compiler was unable to help you. Don't make programming harder than it already is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try directly assigning method to onTap like this...

> onTap: index['onTap']

it will directly replace onTap function coming from list.